# Place 1 double quote around text in excel cell instead of 2 single quotes

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have a worksheet that has all base numbers and letters. I want all the cells that have text to be changed with quotes around them. The code below puts two single quotes around all the cells. Is there any way to place on double quote around the text instead?

Whether I used VBA or tried to do it in excel, I always received errors.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B:B,D:D,F:F").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = """''""@""''"""
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;""''"" @""''"""
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = """''""d-mmm""''"""
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = """''""m/d/yyyy""''"""

    Dim LRow As Long
'
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""''""&0&RC[-8]&""''"""
    Range("I1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I1:I" & LRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLefT

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

for instance

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "\""@\"""
```

so that's "" for the quote within the quoted string prefixed by \ to escape it as a number format character ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For double quotes try using `Chr(34)`.

```
Sub DoubleQuotes
    Dim str as string

    str = "This has double quotes"
    Debug.Print chr(34) & str & chr(34) //Prints "This has double quotes"
End Sub
```

Comment: is tehre a way to print it using chr(34) from inside a macro, like I have? You are suing Debug.Print. Could you write an example line that I could use in that macro above using chr(34)?